# Using a Lambda in a struct initializer

Tags: c++, struct, lambda

I have an array of a struct of which one member is a function pointer. The rest of the members are pure data. The struct and function pointer acts as a poor man's class object and virtual method (pre C++ code C code). The function pointer signature is the same for all instances of the struct.

(Please, no comments about just converting the struct to a class object. I would if I could, but this is part of a huge code base of legacy code. And it's impossible for me to substantially change)

There are several hundred of these structs in one giant array with a giant struct initializer. Each one of these struct's contents are different, each with a different tiny, one-line function to fill the function pointer. This is a maintenance nightmare. I would like to replace these hundreds of tiny functions with just the body of a Lambda directly in the struct initializer itself.

it seems Lambdas are right solution for this, but I'm struggling to figure how, or if this can even be done.

Comment: Based on the description, writing the lambda "in-place" should Just Work. Please post an example of what you tried.

Comment: You don't need to "convert the struct to a class object", In C++, you can do everything you can do with a class with a struct too.

Comment: Please show a [mre] of what you've tried and what if any errors you encountered

Comment: A `struct` and a `class` differ in c++ only in their default access modifier.

Comment: Is this what you want - live - https://godbolt.org/z/jsTq6rbd9  ?

Comment: It would be helpful if you show a [mcve] of your problem case. While I can roughly grasp what your problem is, it is hard to tell if I really understand it correctly. A small code snipped that reflects the problem would make that easier.